# How to get an alert when marker is out from the given area

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I`m new to google maps and i want to get and alert when the mark is not the given area, i have already created the map and i have added a circle to represent the area that marker can allow to move,

[image]

here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Basic Variables
        var map, marker, myLatlng;
        var Location;
        var LAT = 6.9342150;
        var LONG = 79.8919810;



        function loadMap() {

            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LONG);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });


            // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property


            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                // This allows me to drag the mark through map
                draggable: true,
                // Bounce the marker when it adds to the Map
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "Hello World!"


            });

         var CicleOption = {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: myLatlng,
                radius: 1000
            };

            new google.maps.Circle(CicleOption);

            // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
            marker.setMap(marker);


        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadMap()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
</body>
```

I want to get an alert when marker goes out from the circle,

Marker is **draggable**

Thank you.

Comment: You could check if latlng of the marker is still within the range of the circle by adding a dragend-listener. You have to calulate the distance between middle of circle and current position of marker when marker is moved. Check distance is greater then radius then alert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution for you, watch the lines 65 to 77. When the marker is placed outside the circle then it is moved to the middle of the circle again plus the map is centered again.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&language=en"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Basic Variables
        var map, marker, myLatlng;
        var Location;
        var LAT = 6.9342150;
        var LONG = 79.8919810;

        function loadMap() {

            myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(LAT, LONG);
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 14,
                center: myLatlng
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.close();
            });


            // To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property


            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                // This allows me to drag the mark through map
                draggable: true,
                // Bounce the marker when it adds to the Map
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "Hello World!"


            });

         var CicleOption = {
                strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: '#FF0000',
                fillOpacity: 0.35,
                map: map,
                center: myLatlng,
                radius: 1000
            };

            new google.maps.Circle(CicleOption);

            // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();
            marker.setMap(map);


            // THIS IS ADDED

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(event) {

            var currPos = new google.maps.LatLng(event.latLng.k, event.latLng.B);

              var dist = getDistance(currPos, CicleOption.center);

              if(dist > CicleOption.radius){
                 alert('Marker is outside');
                 marker.setPosition(CicleOption.center);
                 map.setCenter(CicleOption.center);
              }

            });

        }

        var rad = function(x) {
          return x * Math.PI / 180;
        };

        var getDistance = function(p1, p2) {
          var R = 6378137; // Earth’s mean radius in meter
          var dLat = rad(p2.lat() - p1.lat());
          var dLong = rad(p2.lng() - p1.lng());
          var a = Math.sin(dLat / 2) * Math.sin(dLat / 2) +
            Math.cos(rad(p1.lat())) * Math.cos(rad(p2.lat())) *
            Math.sin(dLong / 2) * Math.sin(dLong / 2);
          var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
          var d = R * c;
          return d; // returns the distance in meter
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadMap()">
    <div id="map-canvas" style="height:350px;"></div>
</body>
```

Furthermore you can check this by using google-maps-lib:

```
var cirlce = new google.maps.Circle(options);
var bounds = circle.getBounds();

var currPos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.contains(currPos);
```

The method *contains* return a boolean that indicates whether point(currPos) is within circle.

Here is a example of this: http://jsfiddle.net/kaiser/wzcst/

Comment: In your fiddle you are using the LatLngBounds contains method.  A LatLngBounds object is rectangular, not circular, so that doesn't work in the corners.  The equation in the posted code looks right. `dist > CicleOption.radius` should always work (although Cicle is spelled wrong, should be Circle, but it seems to be consistently spelled wrong).